# Form doesn't take me to action url when submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, url, submit

When I submit my form it doesn't take me to the right url, it instead just stays on the same url and adds the params to it. Like this: /todo?message=themessage rather than what it should be as /todo/add

```
<form>
<div class="form-group" action="/todo/add" method="POST">
     <label for="message">Add new todo message</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="message">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>
</form>
```

In my /todo/add url, I have a php script that is assigned to that route, which just echos a string and nothing else to see if the form hit that url, however it does not and just stays on the same page with the params.

Comment: That form is POST, so you won't get $_GET params.

Comment: Set form to method="GET" if you want the values in the URL.

Comment: The POST method is still giving params in the url though, although its just not redirecting to the correct url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it.  All you need to do is to move the "action" and "method" attributes into the form tag instead of the div.

Since you don't have the "action" in the form tag, the default behavior is to submit the form to the same page.

Comment: Oh my god, yeah I see it now. Wow I'm an idiot. Thanks dude. Actually trying to use form attributes inside of a div...

Comment: @DeveloperLewis No problem!  We ALL do things like that, and we never totally stop doing things like that LOL  Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Put the action='' and method='' to form tags, not div

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).